# Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

As google is requiring all new as well as updates to target api level 28.

I have a xamarin android project using visual studio on the PC

Doing so I can not get past the error:

```
Your project does not reference "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0" framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.
```

My project doesnt currently have any nuget packages, so i am completley unaware what they are asking for here.

I have of course attempted to target v9 in the project properites.  This of course updates the project and manifest as expected.

Ive long had the 28 sdk installed, but sure to update my sdks using not only the MS repo but the latest released on the google repo...

Ive also been sure that the correct Mono.Android.dll referance is used and exists:
\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll"

Finally i went and upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 thinking that would fix whatever i have screwed up but it did not.

I then proceeded to try targeting android Q that didnt work either. so im stuck at v8.1 or below.

Ive scoured the internet for answers.
Suggestions ive tried are to be sure the project did not have the Use Latest platform tag, and to run as administrator

Any suggestion apprecated.

Update in response to comments:

Repeating what i said above.  But to provide proof,

> I have of course attempted to target v9 in the project properites.  This of course updates the project and manifest as expected.

- Here is the project file stating the version targeted:

[image]

> Ive long had the 28 sdk installed, but sure to update my sdks using not only the MS repo but the latest released on the google repo...

- Here is the manifest indicating what is targeted:

  [image]

The target version as viewed in properties
[image]

And the compile version set
[image: compile version]

And the current content of the sdk manager
[image: sdk manager]

though i also tried using the google repository and android Q
[image]

And here is the project file contents:

(I should note contrary to the above ive added a nuget package to see if it helps anything)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{C79A7EE8-2CFC-4158-9BE0-D540A39E2823}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{122416d6-6b49-4ee2-a1e8-b825f31c79fe}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MotoApp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MotoApp</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AndroidApplication>True</AndroidApplication>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>false</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AndroidManifest>Properties\AndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>Assets</MonoAndroidAssetsPrefix>
    <AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>False</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
    <BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\CharacteristicMenuItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\DeviceMenuItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\IgnitionGraceItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\IgnitionModeItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\IgnitionStateItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\IgnitionComboItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\SecurityPinItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Ignition\IgnitionGraceActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Ignition\IgnitionModeActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Ignition\IgnitionComboActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Security\SecurityPinActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Security\SecurityActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Devices\DeviceNameActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\ArrayAdapters.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Devices\DevicesActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\FunctionsActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\Ignition\IgnitionActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Ui\MainActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Activities\Interaction\Scaffolding\BaseMenuItem.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App\Common.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
    <None Include="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <None Include="Assets\AboutAssets.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\MainLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\colors.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\ic_launcher_background.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\strings.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\ListLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\ComboLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\TextEditLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\TimeLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\IgnitionLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\PinLayout.axml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AndroidResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MotoBle\MotoBle.csproj">
      <Project>{61a6eb26-f9fc-4c26-8842-b25f6aa2cae1}</Project>
      <Name>MotoBle</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\moto32x32.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
    Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

And here is the project file of the 'MotoBle' library referanced by the main app project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{61A6EB26-F9FC-4C26-8842-B25F6AA2CAE1}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TemplateGuid>{9ef11e43-1701-4396-8835-8392d57abb70}</TemplateGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MotoBle</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MotoBle</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v9.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AdvertisementService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BleDevice.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Constants.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Platform.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Spec\Descriptors\CharacteristicPresentationFormat.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Spec\Descriptors\CharacteristicUserDescription.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Spec\Descriptors\ClientCharacteristicConfiguration.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Spec\Descriptors\DescriptorBase.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Spec\Utilities.cs" />
    <Compile Include="CommandService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GattCallback.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GattCommand.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Resources\Resource.designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Resources\AboutResources.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\values\strings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Resources\drawable\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

i humbly request any info that might help.

Comment: You have to share the content of your project file. Don't make others guess please.

Comment: @axa,Please confirm that you have download android 9.0 sdk by Tools--Android--Android SDK Manager..., then setting Target Android version and Compile using ANdroid version as Android 9.0.

Comment: @LexLi Im not asking anyone to guess, only trust what ive already stated in the original post, that the project file contains the required targetframeworkversion tag.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Bu Indeed I have downloaded sdk v9 via Android SDK Manager, and set the target version as well as the compile versions to 9.  regardless, im puzzled by the error asking to update the nugets that do not exsist.

Comment: The project file is a complete MSBuild script. If you only share one line or two, the culprit can lie in another location there. If you don't want to share the whole file, enable MSBuild diagnostics logging and that is the most detailed information you can use to troubleshoot such.

Comment: @LexLi  I see, so ive added the content of the project file, i am really hoping you might be able to help.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT having android 9.0 sdk , setting targeting and complile version to v 9.0 is there anything else you might suggest i do?
I have been upgrading to 9.0 for a long time becuase of this issue but as of tomrorow, Nov 1 2019, I no longer can avoid it becuase of this problem

Comment: What kind of project is "MotoBle.csproj"? Also from where did you see the error message "Your project does not reference..."? That error message should contain more context than what you typed above. To eliminate all irrelevant parts, please go ahead and create an empty Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio and see if it can compile and run without errors.

Comment: @LexLi  MotoBle is a Xamarin Android Library, I added the project file content to the post.
I had created an empty Xamarin.Android Project which compiled succesfully.
Minding your advise I added the MotoBLE library to the new empty project and it reports the same error.
I then added the contents of the MotoBLE to a new library file in the new empty project and that built fine.
So as every project in the original solution reports the same error, in the original solution i just created a new project for each bad old project and migrated the contents from old to new. now every builds.
Thanks

Comment: ps. perhaps it should , but that error message didnt contain any other context. that was the enteriety of the error.

Comment: @axa, I find you use android Q, where are you using this? Can you provide one sample that can reproduce this issue at github, I will try to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, I installed Android Q from the google repository out of desperation. But in fact the problem would occur regardless of using Pie or Q.

I have recreated all the projects and trashed what was not working, but in insterest to help solve the problem i will reserect the bad code and create a github repo in the next few days.

Comment: Check if you have installed the Android SDK Build Tools 28 (check the tab 'Tools' in your SDK manager) and not only the Android SDK Platform